# Unable to get response from site using POSTMAN

Tags: json, ajax, api, postman

I am sending the following copied CURL request using POSTMAN, but it seems not to work, while same request returned JSON in chrome network tab.

```
curl "https://en.megaubytovanie.sk/Home/ContactOwner" -H "sec-fetch-mode: cors" -H "origin: https://en.megaubytovanie.sk" -H "accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br" -H "accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9,la;q=0.8" -H "x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest" -H "cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=gyqozqt1kfq4sl0iq4wjhy4d; __RequestVerificationToken=x30MpssTRz_dNJ-jipriNdqk8XEAlrm8ItMDDhw_VNIdMqck4sIHvY-_j1VxfexOquOv3MTBXLU_OZkLsy1Yk2MFwS9lP2w55cR3GFSzTyo1; muuid=4a81305922c9467686eb8b6b8f072984; _ga=GA1.3.1647303823.1565426962; _gid=GA1.3.1555882735.1565426962; lctpref=ctest=1^&gateway=28vilsplplb2dt10ot1e692lg7^&uniqid=5d4e85179e9c8; lctsess=ctest=1^&id=5d4e8518; _gat_UA-35708105-1=1" -H "user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Safari/537.36" -H "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" -H "accept: */*" -H "referer: https://en.megaubytovanie.sk/chalupa-bara" -H "authority: en.megaubytovanie.sk" -H "sec-fetch-site: same-origin" --data "__RequestVerificationToken=Qu5dmnEtX_A3TVrjcdFahdoPP-ZmkFAt4IScLGRPSnAMrFx_4R-Sky5h24pryafqCwIR0lEyzMyc_Vy-4_IQY2AiD4vTt2zK3zvKNeNSDiw1^&LodgingObjectId=2454^&AnotherEmail=^&Arrival=17^%^2F08^%^2F2019^&Leave=24^%^2F08^%^2F2019^&AdultCount=5^&ChildrenCount=1^&ChildrenAges^%^5B0^%^5D=-1^&AccommodationUnitsForTabs.AccommodationUnitsForTabs^%^5B0^%^5D.Count=0^&AccommodationUnitsForTabs.AccommodationUnitsForTabs^%^5B0^%^5D.AccommodationUnitId=285^&AccommodationUnitsForTabs.AccommodationUnitsForTabs^%^5B0^%^5D.AccommodationUnitName=Dvojl^%^C3^%^B4^%^C5^%^BEkov^%^C3^%^A1+izba+v+Chalupe+Bara^&AccommodationUnitsForTabs.AccommodationUnitsForTabs^%^5B1^%^5D.Count=0^&AccommodationUnitsForTabs.AccommodationUnitsForTabs^%^5B1^%^5D.AccommodationUnitId=281^&AccommodationUnitsForTabs.AccommodationUnitsForTabs^%^5B1^%^5D.AccommodationUnitName=Trojl^%^C3^%^B4^%^C5^%^BEkov^%^C3^%^A1+izba+v+Chalupe+Bara^&AccommodationUnitsForTabs.AccommodationUnitsForTabs^%^5B2^%^5D.Count=0^&AccommodationUnitsForTabs.AccommodationUnitsForTabs^%^5B2^%^5D.AccommodationUnitId=283^&AccommodationUnitsForTabs.AccommodationUnitsForTabs^%^5B2^%^5D.AccommodationUnitName=^%^C5^%^A0tvorl^%^C3^%^B4^%^C5^%^BEkov^%^C3^%^A1+izba+v+Chalupe+Bara^&AccommodationUnitsForTabs.AccommodationUnitsForTabs^%^5B3^%^5D.Count=0^&AccommodationUnitsForTabs.AccommodationUnitsForTabs^%^5B3^%^5D.AccommodationUnitId=284^&AccommodationUnitsForTabs.AccommodationUnitsForTabs^%^5B3^%^5D.AccommodationUnitName=^%^C5^%^A0tvorl^%^C3^%^B4^%^C5^%^BEkov^%^C3^%^A1+izba+v+Chalupe+Bara^&AccommodationUnitsForTabs.AccommodationUnitsForTabs^%^5B4^%^5D.Count=0^&AccommodationUnitsForTabs.AccommodationUnitsForTabs^%^5B4^%^5D.AccommodationUnitId=282^&AccommodationUnitsForTabs.AccommodationUnitsForTabs^%^5B4^%^5D.AccommodationUnitName=Sedeml^%^C3^%^B4^%^C5^%^BEkov^%^C3^%^A1+izba+v+Chalupe+Bara^&AccommodationUnitsForTabs.AccommodationUnitsForTabs^%^5B5^%^5D.Count=0^&AccommodationUnitsForTabs.AccommodationUnitsForTabs^%^5B5^%^5D.AccommodationUnitId=280^&AccommodationUnitsForTabs.AccommodationUnitsForTabs^%^5B5^%^5D.AccommodationUnitName=Apartm^%^C3^%^A1n+Bara^&LodgingObjectOccupyMax=30^&Description=etsgtegteg^&FullName=aaa+aaaa^&Email=asf^%^40d.com^&PhoneNumber=3075115388^&AnalyticsTrigger=detail_aside" --compressed
```

The site is https://en.megaubytovanie.sk/chalupa-bara, 
Is there something I am missing in the request?

Response I am getting is :

```
{
    "Success": false
}
```

While In chrome it returns

```
"{\"LodgingObjectName\":\"Chalupa Bara\",\"FullName\":\"Renáta Lipovská\",\"Phone\":\"+421 902 277 206\",\"Phone2\":\"+421 902 277 213\",\"Phone3\":\"\",\"Email\":\"ubytovaniebara@gmail.com\",\"Web\":\"\",\"Skype\":\"\",\"NearbyObjects\":[{\"LodgingObjectId\":4357,\"LodgingObjectName\":\"Ubytovanie Hrabušice\",\"ImagePath\":\"31659043-bc50-4387-b1dd-9c2bb2d5b2e3.jpg\"},{\"LodgingObjectId\":2539,\"LodgingObjectName\":\"Apartmány Agnesa\",\"ImagePath\":\"ccc8f4d9-d9ed-417c-98eb-419c95346eb7.jpg\"},{\"LodgingObjectId\":3502,\"LodgingObjectName\":\"Domček Miriam a Privát Milan\",\"ImagePath\":\"da3b7a60-a6e4-484f-bef5-309ce8b1e660.jpg\"},{\"LodgingObjectId\":4478,\"LodgingObjectName\":\"Chata Family\",\"ImagePath\":\"cdcd3d06-b6fd-4fe9-bc97-416893ae8ce7.jpg\"}],\"AnalyticsTrigger\":\"detail_aside\"}"
```

Do share your thoughts,

Comment: works for me in POSTMAN,